# MSSimpleGauge not showing

Tags: ios, xcode, view

Im using MSSimpleGauge with cocoaPods, in a controller view I have the next:

```
self.gauge = [[MSSimpleGauge alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 5, 170, 170)];
self.gauge.startAngle = -40;
self.gauge.endAngle = 220;
self.gauge.value = -60;
self.gauge.fillArcFillColor=gaugeColor;
self.gauge.value=50;
[self.MBMeterContainer addSubview:self.gauge ];
```

I have the gauge declaration as follow

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MSSimpleGauge *gauge;
```

But the gauge is not displayed in the view, wheres my problem?

Comment: is gauge a label? uiview? button? What is it?

Comment: is an MSSimpleGauge object:
https://github.com/sabymike/MSSimpleGauge

Comment: i don't see the usage of iboutlets in the link that you sent me. Can you specify the .h file name?

Comment: the h file of MSSimpleGauge 
https://github.com/sabymike/MSSimpleGauge/blob/master/SimpleGauge/Gauges/MSSimpleGauge.h

Comment: u r adding gauge to meter container. Where are u adding the meter container?

Comment: the metercontainer was created in the storyboard